# how can i change class based radio button group to functional based radio group

Tags: reactjs, radio-group

this is the class based radio group . I want to convert it to functional based radio group. how can i do it. the code is as below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Demo2 extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "React"
    };
    this.onValueChange = this.onValueChange.bind(this);
    this.formSubmit = this.formSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onValueChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      selectedOption: event.target.value
    });
  }

  formSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.selectedOption)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.formSubmit}>
        <div className="radio">
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="Male"
              checked={this.state.selectedOption === "Male"}
              onChange={this.onValueChange}
            />
            Male
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="radio">
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="Female"
              checked={this.state.selectedOption === "Female"}
              onChange={this.onValueChange}
            />
            Female
          </label>
        </div>
```

i want it working code for functional based component. i am new to react pls help.

Comment: Okay, what are the issues you are getting when you make it functional component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a local state using `React.useState` and change the template based on the updated state.

*Note:- `this` operator is not needed for functional components.
And also you can return the template directly (no render method required)

Sample code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function Demo2() {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("Male");

  const onValueChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedOption(event.target.value);
  };

  const formSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(selectedOption);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formSubmit}>
      <div className="radio">
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            value="Male"
            checked={selectedOption === "Male"}
            onChange={onValueChange}
          />
          Male
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="radio">
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            value="Female"
            checked={selectedOption === "Female"}
            onChange={onValueChange}
          />
          Female
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-platform-yr3l9?file=/src/App.js:0-1001

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Demo2() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState("Male");

  const onValueChange = (event) => {
    setChecked(event.target.value);
  };

  const formSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(checked);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formSubmit}>
      <div className="radio">
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            value="Male"
            checked={checked === "Male"}
            onChange={onValueChange}
          />
          Male
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="radio">
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            value="Female"
            checked={checked === "Female"}
            onChange={onValueChange}
          />
          Female
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```